# Send parameter as arrays in Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

how to send parameter as arrays in webservice in c#?

```
public xmlElement insertPurchase(string[] txtproductCode, int[] quantity
    , string user, string password)
{

}
```

how to return xml element from array parameters

Comment: which kind of webservice : asmx or wcf?

Comment: what are the problems you are facing while implementing above ?

Comment: i am getting ouput like this.......... (The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters.....)instead of getting xml

Comment: if i get sample project it ll be more helpful for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change XmlElement to string and return string from method.

```
foreach (string value in txtproductCode)
    {
        // process the value
               string productCode = value ;
    }
```

Comment: i have change xml to string......but i want some syntax to pass array values to dataset....

Comment: Exactly what u wana to convert, u r getting array values and u can easily convert it into any valid form.